# Excel: Detecting OLE Automation?

Tags: excel, ole

we have a third party program which uses OLE to write Data to Excel. Unfortunately, the programmers of that application do not understand that making excel invisible and hiding updates speed up excel enormously.
At this moment, large jobs take up to 15 minutes to complete which is quite annoying.
Therefore I want to write an Addin, which shuts down visibillity etc. when the program writes to excel. Is there a way to do that? It is the only application which uses this technique, so detecting COM / OLE Interaction would be sufficient.

Comment: how do you call the Addin, via Ribbon or VBA? Application.Screenupdating = true turns this off but this might need to be added into the xll / Addin

Comment: Hello, 
the external program is a standalone app, which uses OLE to communicate with Excel. There is no Addin for this program. 
I have no way to influence the programmers of the standalone program, so I hope to detect the OLE-communication. The program does basically this:
1. open excel and create a file
2. write data to excel
3. save and exit excel.

Comment: the logic would be to add in the Workbook_Open the ability to set screenupdating to false and then in Workbook_Close to set it back to true. If you have no control of the creation of the file this is not possible so either you need to speak with the programmers of the tool and convince them or its not possible. Even if you knew how to detect the OLE process there would be no place to add the code as the app creates a fresh copy of Excel.

Comment: I think it is possible: Addins are loaded by Excel on each start, so when it launches, the Addin could look for com activities.

Answer (score 1):

Rather that have excel check to see if it is in the hands of OLE automation, it is possible to check windows for the name of the process that is runnning the OLE

something like

```
Function isRunning(ProcessName) As Boolean

Dim objWMIcimv2 As Object
Dim objList As Object

Set objWMIcimv2 = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2") 'Connect to CIMV2 Namespace

Set objList = objWMIcimv2.ExecQuery _
("select * from win32_process where name='" & ProcessName & "'")

If objList.Count > 0 Then

  isRunning = True

End If
End Function
```

From there you can suppress screen updating pretty easily. I am making a guess that the third party application doesn't usually sit running idle on the users desktop. if it does then obviously this approach won't help you.

Code inspired from this [link](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=811%20link) on terminating programs

Comment: Is this possible for a command line application?
The legacy app looks like this: 
GUI which calls a windowless cmd-application with parameters.

Your solution is quite interesting, thank you!

Comment: yes... the command line .exe file should show up in the process list when you execute it. I just tested with ruby ole and the code above was able to detect it.

Comment: Thank you! I will try after christmas and then report back.